# Set Height of Bootstrap Accordion to Fill Parent Container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to create an accordion using Bootstrap. I'd like the expanded accordion item to fill the entire height of the accordion's parent div.

In an example scenario, if we assume the parent div has a fixed height of 500px, how would I make each accordion item fill the entire height of the parent div when expanded?

If I set the height of the divs with the collapse class, the height of the expanded item changes, but the animation then jumps when expanding. I would assume the animation height calculation does not take into account the height of the collapse div.

In the event the parent isn't a fixed height, how could I have the accordion items dynamically expand to fill the entire div height?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion" style="background-color: black;" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Accordion Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          First Item Body
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Accordion Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>

      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Second Item Body
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```